# Crawl the content of external documents in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: 2007, crawling

Does anybody know if it's possible to crawl the content of documents that are not in a document library?

Imagine a situation where a different document management tool is used to manage documents stored in some network shared folder and we want SharePoint to crawl the content of those documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can crawl file shares with SharePoint 2007. This is how you [can configure crawling](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263230%28office.12%29.aspx), then you should configure [full crawl](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263311%28office.12%29.aspx) and [incremental crawl schedule](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263373%28office.12%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In the Shared Service provider in Central Administration, create a new Content SOurce in the Search Settings.  Point it at your file share and set a crawl schedule.